# Method in base class that returns derived class type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, return-type, generic-programming

I have a bunch of classes that have one function in common, except that it returns a pointer to their own type. The code looks the same and I would like to move that into an abstract base class. But how can I make classes that inherit from it return their own type?

```
class base {
    base *foo() {
        // ...
    }
};


class derived : public base {

};

derived d;
d.foo(); // Should return derived* instead of base*
```

Is there a way to express this in C++?

Comment: Interesting reading : http://nerdland.net/2009/06/covariant-templatized-virtual-copy-constructors/

Comment: I would argue that doing what you want to achieve doesn't make a lot of sense. In order for the function body to be the same, the object that is returned must be referenced in the function body through a common base-derived class interface. This means either another virtual function or the this pointer. In any case, the function returns a real derived class object. Knowing this a possible solution would be to simply downcast the pointer using a helper function.

Comment: This seems a common issue when trying to build fluent interfaces with inheritance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, C++ supports this. It's called *covariant return types*. You just have to declare the function virtual and declare the return types accordingly. That's all there is to it.

```
struct base {
    virtual base *foo() {
        // ...
    }
};


struct derived : public base {
    virtual derived *foo() {
        // ...
    }
};

derived d;
base *base_ptr = d.foo();
```

---

Now a comment of yours extends the original question:

> But actually my goal is to not repeat the function body since it's the
>   same except the used type.

This is not possible.

There are various techniques which can *facilitate* the repeating, but you won't get around the fact that whatever you do, you still have to create the function bodies yourself.

One such technique would be using macros, at the cost of **obfuscation and all other disadvantages that come with macros**; but still, the macro won't appear in the classes automatically. You have to put it there.

```
// beware of macros!
#define FOO(T) virtual T *foo() { return new T; }

struct base {
    FOO(base)
    virtual ~base() {} // let's not forget the virtual destructor
};


struct derived : public base {
    FOO(derived)
};
```

A similar approach is to facilitate the repeating of the function bodies with a **template**:

```
template <class T>
T *ComplicatedFunctionReturningT()
{
    T *t;
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...
    return t;
}

struct base {
    virtual base *foo() {
        return ComplicatedFunctionReturningT<base>();
    }
    virtual ~base() {} // let's not forget the virtual destructor
};


struct derived : public base {
    virtual derived *foo() {
        return ComplicatedFunctionReturningT<derived>();
    }
};
```

Templates are safer then macros.

---

Another approach is to use the Template Method design pattern. If a lot of code is repeated in the function body of every class, try to move as much as possible in the base class and put the small abstract part into a private function to be overridden:

```
class base {
public:
    base *foo() { // no longer virtual
        // ...
        // ...
        base *ptr = fooImpl();
        // ...
        // ...
        return ptr;
    }

    virtual ~base() {} // let's not forget the virtual destructor

private:
    virtual base *fooImpl() = 0; // pure virtual and private
};

class derived1 : public base {
private:
    virtual derived1 *fooImpl() {
        return new derived1; // very simple body
    }
};

class derived2 : public base {
private:
    virtual derived2 *fooImpl() {
        return new derived2; // very simple body
    }
};
```

---

Of course, all of this is really only worth it if the function bodies are really complicated. For extreme cases, an entirely different approach is to **generate the C++ code using some external tool or script**.

And finally, if this is really a problem, reconsider your design as a whole. Perhaps it turns out you don't really need the function, or you don't need OOP for the actual problem your program attempts to solve.

Comment: Alright that's a start. But actually my goal is to not repeat the function body since it's the same except the used type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for walking me through the different options! I like the template method approach, it introduces a bit of extra complexity but still is the best fit. Yes, reconsidering my design is what I'm doing right now. I'm not yet satisfied with it but I don't have a better idea at the moment.

Comment: @danijar: Actually, in C++ the *default* should be to make virtual member functions private and public ones non-virtual. Public virtual functions should be an exception to the rule (except of destructors, of course). See this old article by Herb Sutter: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Comment: Actually I don't use classes in the OOP sense. It is just a way of deferring shared code and defining interfaces for me.

Comment: @danijar: With the usual definition of OOP, the presence of a single virtual function makes your class an OOP class. But that's hair-splitting. There's a hardly a word in the world of software engineering as overloaded and abused as "OOP" :)

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment to Christians answer, you could implement a template helper method to not duplicate code you would be using:

```
class base 
{
  protected:
    template<class T> T* fooInternal()
    {
        T* t = new T();

        // do stuff with t

        return t;
    }
  public:
    virtual base* foo() { return fooInternal<base>(); }
};


class derived : public base 
{
  public:
    virtual derived* foo() { return fooInternal<derived>(); }
};
```

Comment: Okay I think this is what I'll use. There's one more thing, I also have a stl container like `std::unordered_map<std::string, base*>` that should be inherited into derived classes as `std::unordered_map<std::string, derived*>`. Is there a way to do this? I thought about type traits but couldn't figure out how to apply them here.

Comment: @danijar: You cannot override member variables; you have to declare it in every class. But you can use similar techniques as for the functions. For example, use multiple inheritance (public + private) with a template. `template<class T> struct ContainsMap { std::unordered_map<std::string, T*> map; }; class derived : public base, private ContainsMap<derived> { /* ... */};`

Comment: So the solution is just to put all common code into the base class and *make it templated*. That sounds good.

Comment: @danijar: More or less. The danger is always that of **over-engineering**. The technique looks cool and can easily lure you into the solution-in-search-of-a-problem realm. If you are not sure it's worth the trouble, just keep it simple and repeat the declarations in every class.

Comment: Alright. It seems like I can't apply this anyway when I want to access nested types like `T::sub_type` since the dependent scope must be known first. However, the way around might be in the article Jarod42 posted above.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (Curiously recurring template pattern).

```
template<typename Derived>
struct base {
    Derived* foo() {
        // ...
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};

struct derived : base<derived> {
    // ...
};

derived d;
derived *derived_ptr = d.foo();
```

The primary benefits are that you don't need macros nor virtual methods to get the type you care about.

If you are doing this with multiple methods in the base class, it can be nice to define a helper method.

```
template<typename Derived>
struct base {
    Derived* foo() {
        // ...
        return self();
    }

private:
    Derived* self() {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};
```

I've used this pattern, for instance, for property objects where I have a base set of shared properties and several derived property objects with their own properties.  I then have the base class methods return a reference to the derived class so that I can chain setting multiple properties on the same statement.

```
    SomePropertyObject()
        .setBaseProperty("foo")
        .setDerivedProperty("bar");
```